# Is there a way to get GraphicsPath of a window?

Tags: mfc, gdi+, win32gui, graphicspath

I'm trying to frame a window using GDI+ Graphics class in OnPaint(). Since DrawPath() function requires GraphicsPath, Is there a way to get GraphicsPath of a window ?

Answer (score 1):

Why not use `DrawRectangle(Pen*,Rect&)` instead. It only requires a rectangle and you can easily get that with `GetClientRect()`.

Comment: Unfortunately, the window I want to set a border around is a custom clipped window (intersection of a rectangle and rounded rectangle) created using SetWindowRgn(). I can probably create a GraphicsPath by adding a few arcs and rectangle but I'm looking for a generic way to get a path from already existing window.